# MySQL Table with ~20Mil rows - Queries getting slow

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my MySQL(5.7.32) database which currently has 20Mil rows. I have a few fairly complex queries written on that table, where I carry out FullTextSearches and join them to other tables. The queries on the table are getting slow (using appropriate indexes).

I understand that 20 Mil rows are not a lot for a DB table to handle, and would like to understand what are the factors (other than indexes) that I should consider for performance improvements. For example, any DB defaults that I should consider changing that impact performance.

NOTE: Since the table has FTS indexes, partitioning is not an option.

Comment: Go for partitioning

Comment: @AmitVerma: Since we perform FTS searches on the table, and the table has FTS Indexes, partitioning is not an option.

Comment: Are you using more than just one FTS in the query?  Please show us the query, its `EXPLAIN`, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of factors that could hurt performance:

- Buffer pool not large enough to hold the index. So as a query searches the index, it has to keep swapping parts of the index into RAM and back out. You may need to increase the `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

  I'd monitor the ratio of the two numbers reported by `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_read%s'`.
- CPU is too slow. Each query is single-threaded, so CPU speed is more important than number of cores.
- Concurrent load. If you have many queries running at the same time, they compete with each other for CPU, buffer pool, and I/O. Check SHOW PROCESSLIST or `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Threads_running'`.
- Server is overloaded, either by MySQL or by other apps or processes. Use `top` to find out if the system load average is high (I would consider anything over 10 to be too high), or if the system is using swap space instead of RAM.
- Is the query using indexes like you expect? Did you analyze them with EXPLAIN?